# Is it safe to leave out ctx.Done() when using the Go Context package?

Tags: go

I am looking for a way to "cancel" a method based off of how much time has passed since its execution. The context package looks to be a good way to achieve this goal in stead of needing to write out all the "wait for x amount of time to pass" logic.

The code I'm using to test options and learn how context in Go operates is as follows.

```golang
func runit() {
    var i uint8
    for i < 5 {
        fmt.Println(i)
        i++
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    go runit()

    select {
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
        return
    }
}
```

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/VPUCUgRACRU)

The examples and tutorials I've see contain `case <-ctx.Done():` but in my situation `ctx.Done()` will execute before the three seconds are up.

Is it safe to leave it off since in this case the main function will finish and in turn cancel the Goroutine?

Comment: `ctx.Done()` returns a channel, channels don't require any special treatment (from memory perspective): just stop using it and it will eventually be GCed.

Comment: If you are trying to cancel `runit` then you need to pass the context to it and return when the context has expired.  In the code above the go-routine executing `runit` will run for 5 seconds (but will be unceremoniously terminated when main exits). In `main` the context expires after a sec. but never gets tested for another 2 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: It **is** safe to leave out `ctx.Done()`.  The channel returned by `Done()` is not always necessary, it's just that in many uses of a context a go-routine is waiting on one or channels and needs to also wait for the context so it can abort its operation.  In other words it waits on the channel returned from `ctx.Done()` and other channel(s) using a `select` statement.

But if you are just running some calcs in a potentially long-running loop then you don not need to used `Done()` but can just check if `Err()` returns a non-nil value.

I hope I am right in guessing that this is what you want:

```
func runit(ctx context.Context) {
    for i := 0;  i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        if ctx.Err() != nil {
            return // abort the calcs
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    runit(ctx)
    fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
}
```

Or maybe you want to try context in a select:

```
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Context cancelled (after 1 second)")
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("Not Done")
    }
```

Comment: Aw thank you! This is what I was looking for and nowhere was anyone talking about killing a process if it takes longer than a certain amount of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

When the context times out, it closes the channel returned by `ctx.Done()`, so you can check if the context timed out.

```
select {
    case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println(ctx.Err())
        return
    case <-ctx.Done():
        // Context timed out
        return
}
```

Your context times out in a second, but the select will wait 3 seconds, so to get the context timeout, you have to use the `Done()` channel.

Without using the `Done()` channel, it is meaningless to use a context with timeout. That's the only way you can receive the timeout event.